# Probability of circuit operation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a question, which is relate to the [following topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927234/given-that-the-system-works-compute-the-probability-that-component-is-working/3614769#3614769).

Assuming the following [circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmjMr.png), the probability that the entire system works is given by:
$$P[X]\cup P[Y] = P[X] + P[Y] - P[X\cap Y],$$

given P[X] is defined by the branch AB and P[Y] by CDE. Now, what is the probability that A is not working given the system works?

I would write it as

$$P[A'|Z] = \frac{P[A'\cap Z]}{P[Z]},$$
where $P[Z]=P[X]\cup P[Y].$
Intuitively, one could consider
$P[A']\cap P[Z] = P[A']P[Z]$. However, this only holds when $A'$ and $Z$ are independent. Since the system works independently from branch $AB$ when $C$, $D$ and $E$ are working, one could use $P[A'\cap (C\cap D \cap E)] = P[A']P[C]P[D]P[E]$.
Finally, I reach my question. Why should one still use $P[Z]$ in the denominator, i.e.,
$$P[A'|Z] = \frac{P[A'\cap (C\cap D \cap E)]}{P[Z]}\quad (1)$$ rather than
$$P[A'|C\cap D \cap E] = \frac{P[A'\cap (C\cap D \cap E)]}{P[C\cap D \cap E]}\quad (2)?$$

Equation (1) must be used in order to reach the same answer as given in the book. However, it bugs me that the conditional probability equation requires an "adaptation".

Answer (score 1):

The question is to calculate the probability that A is not working knowing the system works so $$P[A'|Z] = \frac{P[A'\cap (C\cap D \cap E)]}{P[Z]}\quad (1)$$

as you mentioned it.

The second equation you wrote is literally what is the probability that A is not functioning knowing the bottom branch is working. You would agree that the bottom branch working or not has nothing to do with A working or not, hence those two events are independent and you get simply:

$$P[A'|\cap (C\cap D \cap E)] = P[A'] * P[C\cap D \cap E]\quad (2)$$

Comment: This does not fully answer my question. Why "bending" the conditional probability equation, i.e., $P[A|Z] = P[A]P[W]/P[Z]$, is the way to go? In (1), Replacing $Z$ in the numerator by $C\cap D\cap E$ gives me the idea that the following must be true $Z=C\cap D\cap E$ and it's not, otherwise we would also have $C\cap D\cap E$ in the denominator.

Comment: Z=C∩D∩E  is not true they are not similar events.
You should not be confused by the fact that maybe in this case,  those events have the same probability.
Said differently, imagine that P(Z) was equal to 1/6 you would not have concluded that event Z is the same as  getting a 6 with a faire dice !